# Find the probability that only one of the numbers drawn is prime

Tags: probability

Bag A contains 5 balls with numbers 1,3,5,7 ,9 printed on them .

Bag B contains 5 balls with numbers 2,4,6,8,10 printed on them

A ball is randomly picked from each bag . (Picking 1 ball from bag A and then 2nd pick from bag B)

Find the probability that only one of the numbers drawn is prime.

Comment: It will be $3/10$

Comment: Are the two bags equally probable?  And what do you mean "one of the numbers"?  Are we taking one from each bag?

Comment: @ArchisWelankar  $\frac {4}{10}$.  Don't forget $2$.

Comment: I must be misreading something, but cannot actually understand the question. You have **two** bags, then pick a ball (uniformly) at random from "the bag."  Which one?

Comment: Hint:  assuming you mean "draw one ball from each bag" then it is easier to work with the complement.  The probability that the $A$ ball is composite is $\frac 25$.  For $B$ ball it is $\frac 45$.  Can you finish?

Comment: Yes it is $2/5$

Comment: Except that I expect the OP means something else entirely since there is a reference to "one of the numbers drawn".  It needs to be clarified.

Comment: @lulu yes only 1 of the numbers drawn must be prime . If both are prime then it's not counted

Comment: @user307640 So you are picking one ball from the first bag and one ball from the second bag?

Comment: @NobleMushtak yes

Comment: @user307640  Can you edit your question?  It's clear that the wording is confusing.  In any case, using the numbers from my prior comment, the probability that the $A$ ball is prime but the $B$ ball is composite is $\frac 35 \times \frac 45$. Can you finish it from here?

Comment: @user307640  I see the edit but you should still specify that you mean "exactly one of the two balls is prime".  I think most readers (well, me anyway) would assume that you meant "at least one".

Comment: @lulu "Only" and "exactly" basically mean the same thing.

Comment: @NobleMushtak  Yes, but the "only" was just now added.

Comment: @lulu   Oh yes , I understand better now . Thanks all!

Comment: "only one" = "at most one" or "exactly one"???

Comment: @barakmanos exactly one

Answer (score 3):

There are two cases where this can happen:

- Ball from Bag A is prime and Ball from Bag B is composite

The probability that the ball from Bag A is prime is $\frac 3 5$ since there are $3$ primes in a $5$-ball bag. Also, the probability that the ball from Bag B is composite is $\frac 4 5$ since there are $4$ composites in a $5$-ball bag. In order to find probabilities of two events happening at the same time, we multiply them to get $\frac 3 5*\frac 4 5=\frac{12}{25}$.

- Ball from Bag A is composite and Ball from Bag B is prime

The probability that the ball from Bag A is composite is $\frac 2 5$ since there are $2$ primes in a $5$-ball bag. Also, the probability that the ball from Bag B is composite is $\frac 1 5$ since there is $1$ prime in a $5$-ball bag. In order to find probabilities of two events happening at the same time, we multiply them to get $\frac 2 5*\frac 1 5=\frac{2}{25}$.

Now, to find the probability of the whole event, we add up the probability of each case to get $\frac{12}{25}+\frac{2}{25}=\frac{14}{25}$ as our final answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Split it into disjoint events, and then add up their probabilities:**

---

The probability that the ball from bag $\color\red{A}$ is prime and the ball from bag $\color\green{B}$ is not prime:

$$\frac{\color\red3}{5}\cdot\frac{5-\color\green1}{5}=\frac{12}{25}$$

---

The probability that the ball from bag $\color\red{A}$ is not prime and the ball from bag $\color\green{B}$ is prime:

$$\frac{5-\color\red3}{5}\cdot\frac{\color\green1}{5}=\frac{2}{25}$$

---

Hence the overall probability:

$$\frac{12}{25}+\frac{2}{25}=\frac{14}{25}$$